# What is the meaning of "Spiraling"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

On Twitter I see people say things like

*her guilt is spiraling*

Or

*spiraling into madness*

What does this mean?

Comment: It's metaphorical. Flushing water down the toilet. Going from mostly stable to a much lower turbulent space.

Answer (score 2):

When falling from the sky birds, or aircraft, that are no longer aerodynamically balanced for whatever reason, go into a "death spiral". I believe the saying "spiraling out of of control" comes from this motion, from which many other similar uses are derived.

Answer (score -1):

**spiralling** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/186807?redirectedFrom=spiralling#eid21458614) adj. and n.

As in:

> 1969   H. Perkin Key Profession iv. 138   The post-war situation of
>   [upward] spiralling prices and incomes.

I give an example.  I will allow you to look up the definitions of spirla.